# How many http requests do I make, when I request the document page with Requests in Python 3.9?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using a python script to parse a website via proxy. Said proxy implements a limit on how many concurrent requests can I make. When running a single thread of my python application, I encountered my proxy provider rate limiting me and I wonder, if I am really making more than 1 request when I run  `requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)` Shouldn’t this only return the document page without any other resources?

Comment: no.... `requests.get(url)` is only making one request  (of coarse your proxy could be making a bunch of requests... but its impossible for anyone on this site to say if thats happening(unlikely))

Comment: Maybe your proxy recognizes that a script instead of a browser is running the request and blocks it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As tested below, a single request is sent.
Maybe what is happening is that your proxy provider has some mechanism to detect bots, and is blocking your script.

This mechanism could use anything from user agent, to how the packets are sent.
[image: python on left, node server on right]

Comment: Thanks, I did expect that it is only a single request. Proxy provider has no issues with bot requests, because that is to who he offers his services in the first place. I wonder if perhaps the issue is that his server is leaving connections open long after forwarding me the response. That could explain, how I keep running into the limit (which is a pretty low one, a few concurrent requests). Or some kind of network congestion that causes my requests to arrive too close together.